# DBCC CHECKDB did not return a result set in Java ( MS SQL )

Tags: java, sql-server, resultset, executequery, dbcc

Here is my Function:

```
private static void checkDatabase(String dbName, String password) {
    try{
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database="+dbName+ ";user=SA;password=" +password);
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("DBCC CHECKDB;");
        while(rs.next()){
          System.out.println( //TODO );
        }
            con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
}
```

1. I wanna use DBCC CHECKDB to check all Databases but got this Error:

   ```
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
   ```

   Why DBCC CHECK DB can not work with executeQuery() and how can i fix it ?
2. So if i have already ResultSet from stmt.executeQuery(), how can i read this Result as Lines or String? I want to read how many Errors are there. Thank you.

Comment: DBCC CHECKDB returns results as messages rather than a result set by default. Either specify the `TABLERESULTS` option (`DBCC CHECKDB WITH TABLERESULTS;`) or execute the query with a method that doesn't return a result set.

Comment: thanks. it will help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

`DBCC CHECKDB` returns results as messages rather than a result set by default. Specify the `TABLERESULTS` option (`DBCC CHECKDB WITH TABLERESULTS;`) so results are returned as rows instead of messages.

Alternatively, you could use the `execute` method instead of `executeQuery` and get the returned messages using `getWarnings`:

```
stmt.execute("DBCC CHECKDB;");
SQLWarning w = stmt.getWarnings();
while(w != null) {
    System.out.println(w.getMessage());
    w = w.getNextWarning();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Boolean rs = stmt.execute("DBCC CHECKDB;"); instead.

Some SQL statements don't return a resultset.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).